# How to create an onPress event that dismisses a callout?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm building a gig guide in React Native, using react native maps.

Users are presented with a Map with markers indicating the location of gig. When these markers are tapped, a callout pops up with gig information:

[image]

When the user taps the "Next day's gigs" button, the map is rendered with markers showing the upcoming day's gigs. When the user hits this button, **I want to make sure that any open callouts on the current day are dismissed when the button is hit**. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Here's the code from the component rendering the map:

**GigMap.js**

```
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Pressable,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { Marker, Callout } from "react-native-maps";
import CalloutView from "./CalloutView";
import { mapStyle } from "../util/mapStyle";
import { useGigs } from "../hooks/useGigs";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";


const GigMap = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [selectedDateMs, setSelectedDateMs] = useState(Date.now());
  const gigs = useGigs();


  //generates current date in format DD/MM/YYYY
  const selectedDateString = useMemo(() => {
    const date = new Date(selectedDateMs);
    const dateToString = date.toString().slice(0,15)
    return dateToString // returns in form 'Tue Dec 20 2022'
  }, [selectedDateMs]);


  //Filtering through gigs to return only current day's gigs
  const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => {
    const gigDate1 = new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds*1000)   
    const gigDate2 = gigDate1.toString().slice(0,15) //return form 'Tue Dec 20 2022'
    return gigDate2 === selectedDateString
  })


  //increments date by amount
  const addDays = (amount) => {
    setSelectedDateMs((curr) => curr + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * amount);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>{`Gigs on ${selectedDateString}`}</Text>

      <View style={styles.imageText}>
        <Text style = {styles.subHeader}>Tap on</Text>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require("../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png")}
        />
        <Text style = {styles.subHeader}> to see gig info</Text>
      </View>

      <MapView
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: -41.29416,
          longitude: 174.77782,
          latitudeDelta: 0.03,
          longitudeDelta: 0.03,
        }}
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
      >
        {gigsToday.map((gig, i) => (
          <Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: gig.location.latitude,
              longitude: gig.location.longitude,
            }}
            image={require("../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png")}
            description = 'test'
          >
            <Callout
              style={styles.callout}
              tooltip={true}
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate("GigDetails", {
                  venue: gig.venue,
                  date: selectedDateString,
                  gigName: gig.gigName,
                  image: gig.image
                })
              }
            >
              <CalloutView
                venue={gig.venue}
                gigName={gig.gigName}
                genre = {gig.genre}
              />
            </Callout>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </MapView>

      <View style={styles.buttonOptions}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(-1)} style = {styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={36} color="#778899" />
          <Text style = {{fontFamily:'Helvetica-Neue', color:'#778899'}}>Previous day's gigs</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(1)} style = {styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretright" size={36} color="#778899" />
          <Text style = {{fontFamily:'Helvetica-Neue',color:'#778899'}}>Next day's gigs</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>

  );
};
```

**CalloutView.js**

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const CalloutView = ({ venue,gigName,genre }) => {
    const title = gigName.substring(0,25)
    return ( 
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <Text style = {styles.header} >{`${title}`}</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.details}>{`${venue} | ${genre}`}</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.button}>Tap to see details</Text>
        </View>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import React from "react";
import { IMAGES } from "theme";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker, Callout } from "react-native-maps";

const GigMap = () => {
  return (
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
      style={styles.map}
      region={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
     }}
   >
     <Marker
       coordinate={{
       latitude: 37.78825,
       longitude: -122.4324,
       }}
       image={IMAGES.MAP_MARKER}
       title="Test Title"
       description="This is the test description"
     >
    <Callout tooltip>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.bubble}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.name}>Gig Title</Text>
          <Text>A Gig description</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.arrowBorder} />
        <View style={styles.arrow} />
      </View>
    </Callout>
  </Marker>
</MapView>
);
};

export default GigMap;



const styles = StyleSheet.create({


map: {
  height: "100%",
},
// Callout bubble
bubble: {
 flexDirection: "column",
 alignSelf: "flex-start",
 backgroundColor: "#fff",
 borderRadius: 6,
 borderColor: "#ccc",
 borderWidth: 0.5,
 padding: 15,
 width: 150,
},
// Arrow below the bubble



arrow: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "transparent",
    borderTopColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 16,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: -32,
  },
  arrowBorder: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "transparent",
    borderTopColor: "#007a87",
    borderWidth: 16,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: -0.5,
  },
  // Gig Title
  name: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  // Gig button
  button: {
    width: "40%",
    height: 80,
  },
});
```

**Here is some of the Suggestions for you**

- use numberOfLines for title
- use [Dayjs](https://day.js.org/) instead of manually doing date.toString().slice(0,15) also it will be solve your all dates and time related problems